# In CKAN, how do I make 'groups' in the package schema required?

Tags: validation, schema, ckan

In CKAN, atomic properties of the package schema are defined as lists of validators. To make a property required, I can use the `not_empty` validator. E.g., to make the `author` property required, I could define it in the schema as follows:

```py
{
    ...
    'author': [not_empty, unicode_safe] ,
    ...
}
```

However, the `groups` property is not atomic, and the schema definition is a dict (the schema for groups), rather than a list of validators. So, my question is: **how can I define a package schema that requires at least one group to be present?**

I know it is possible to simply say `'groups': [not_empty]`, but then the nested schema definition for `group` is lost.

(I also know that I would have to adjust the package template to enable mandatory groups, but that is another matter)

Answer (score 1):

After some further research and experimentation, I can answer my own question here: the key is to implement [IDatasetForm.validate()](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IDatasetForm.validate), which can be used to validate packages in ways that go beyond the schema-based validation usually employed:

```py
from ckan.common import _
import ckan.plugins.toolkit as toolkit

def validate(self, context, data_dict, schema, action):

    # first, run the schema-based validation to get that out of the way:
    (data_dict, errors) = toolkit.navl_validate(data_dict, schema, context)

    # we're only interested if this is a create or update action:
    if action in [ 'package_create', 'package_update' ]:
        # now comes the actual validation:
        if 'groups' not in data_dict:
            errors['groups'] = errors.get('groups', []) + [ _('Required field \'groups\' not set.') ]
        else if len(data_dict['groups'] < 1):
            errors['groups'] = errors.get('groups', []) + [ _('\'groups\' property has no value.') ]
        # we should probably also check if the group exists, etc.

    return (data_dict, errors)
```

This should work well for package creation/updating via the API. If we want to make this work for creation and updating via the UI, we also have to adjust the package template to allow the setting of `groups` on the main template - otherwise there might be an error on the main template which the user won't be able to fix.

Comment: To add some more reference for others, here's some docs on schemas and validation https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#ckan-schemas-and-validation.  And a reference to some validator functions showing some of what's available https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/validators.html.  The scheming extension is another option and would allow you to flag a field as required. https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming